springBoot + Thymeleaf: set Page language based on Locale
I've tried with:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="${locale.language}">

and
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="${#locale.language}">

but does not work

You need to use the Thymeleaf specific attribute, otherwise it won't function:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      th:lang="${#locale.language}">

...

